# Auto increment in mysql by more than 1

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have an invoicing system that runs off an sql db.
Every time I create a new invoice, the invoice number increases by 1.

So invoice number 5000, the next is 5001, then 5002 and so on.
I want so that the next invoice number increased by a different number, Say 15.

So invoice number 5000, then 5015, then 5030 etc.

Is it possible to change something in phpmyadmin to achieve this.

TIA

Comment: Warning! The tax man will think that is odd enough to come take a very close look

Comment: What RiggsFolly said is very true, and if the company you work for gets regular Inspections. this will be questioned since you will be missing invoice numbers. and a further investigation can take place.

Comment: While the tax man will think it odd, the investigation would end with "nothing amiss" unless you've done something else. This is not something I would do, but it is not illegal. Just.. odd.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, do note that this is global, and not just one table. If you are going to just have this happen on one table, create an stored procedure to set the id instead of auto increment.

```
SET @@auto_increment_increment=2;
SET @@auto_increment_offset=2;
```

Documentation:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replication-options-source.html#sysvar_auto_increment_increment

You can also just have a subquery decide what the invoice no is supposed to be and not have it autoincremented. I would suspect that this code should be written in the invoicing software itself (Which might not be possible, in your case, at which point my top example is the only way to go) but if you can edit the software, you simply need to select the highest invoice that exists, and then + 2 - then store that in the column you present.

Comment: just out of curiosity, how would said SP work? would they need to select the last ID and then add 15 to it before using Insert?

Comment: @Demeteor Yes, precisely. You would not use auto increment at that point, but as you said, an ID that is calculated based off of the last ID. So essentially you do an select max on id, then use that value + 2 to store, just like if you did the change in the software itself. - Again though, if you want to you can keep the ID as is, and simply create a new column called invoice_number instead of using an invoice_id or something like that and present that instead - with this calculation above.

Comment: okay cheers !  I did not ask the original question but I find it fun learning when I get the chance

Comment: Definitely, always good to learn. Did my response here above answer your question though? Regarding auto_increment_increment and auto_increment_offset, or are you still having issues?

Comment: I was not the original guy who asked it ^^ but yeah for me it clear things out

Comment: Haha, sorry @Demeteor

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with two columns. One `ID` with normal auto increment and one `InvoiceNumber` with a default value of (ID * 15):

```
ALTER TABLE `definitions`
    ADD COLUMN `InvoiceNumber` INT NOT NULL DEFAULT (ID * 15) AFTER `DisplayOrder`;
```

Answer (score 0):

I know that you can modify the step in mySQL, but it is a global change which would affect all tables. I suggest that you leave the data as is and use a view to multiply the values by 15.
Obviously you will replace the column **description** with a number of columns with the real information, date, customer etc. etc.

```
create table invoice_data(
id int primary key AUTO_INCREMENT,
description varchar(100)
);
```

```
create view invoices as
select
15 * id as invoice_number,
description
from invoice_data;
```

```
insert into invoice_data (description) values
('invoice 1 information'),('invoice 2 information');
```

```
select * from invoices;
```

```
invoice_number | description          
-------------: | :--------------------
            15 | invoice 1 information
            30 | invoice 2 information
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=1bc556520ef57b5ad98071fb0c047f65)*